# Install python package from local directory and remove said directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-packaging

I've written a python package that I would like to share with my coworkers, but I can't find how to install it alongside other packages installed through pip.

When issuing the following command, the package is successfully installed and I can use the package from anywhere on the system:

```
$ git clone git.adress.com/greatmodule.git
$ cd greatmodule
$ pip install .
```

However if someone delete the `greatmodule/` directory, the package becomes unusable.

I'd like the module to be installed alongside other packages installed with `pip`, for instance under `C:/Program Files/Python/Lib/site-packages` in my case.

Is that possible / is it recommended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There two better solutions that comes to mind instead of the one you are trying:

### **1. Install from repo**

Pip supports installing a package from a git repository.

For example lets suppose you connect to your remote repository via ssh you can use the following (assuming:

```
pip3 install git+ssh://git@git.address.com/greatmodule.git
```

If you are using https to connect to repo:

```
pip3 install git+https://git.address.com/greatmodule.git
```

If using a specific branch:

```
pip3 install git+https://git.address.com/greatmodule.git@branch-name
```

### **2. Add package as submodule (ADVANCED)**

Add repo as submodule:

```
git submodule add https://git.address.com/greatemodule.git
```

Then add submodule to **PYTHONPATH**

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/directory_absolute_path
```

Then you can create source distribution (you'll need to package your app using setup.py that it should contain your packages names and versions)

```
python3 setup.py -q sdist --dist-dir=../package_directory
```

Then you can install the source distribution as normal package